# Prevent Smart Card prompt when looking for Enrollment Certificate

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, template, smartcard

I'm using an Enrollment Agent user certificate to amend CSRs (in order to add SANs)

My method is working fine - using the following command:

```
certreq -config "CertAuth" -policy "PathtoCSR" "Path to SanDetails.inf" "NewCSROutputPath"
```

But when I submit the request it first prompts me for a Smart Card:

[image: SmartCardPrompt Image]

If I cancel this prompt it then prompts for the Enrollment Agent user certificate I have on my PC:

[image: Enrollment Cert Prompt Image]

Is there a way to avoid the Smart Card prompt? Can I do this by specifying a CSP in the template?

Is there also a way to avoid the confirmation prompt for the user certificate?

As per comments below - I have confirmed the syntax for specifying the certificate to use is correct as:

```
certreq -config "CertAuth" -policy -cert "thumbprint" "PathtoCSR" "Path to SanDetails.inf" "NewCSROutputPath
```

However I am still getting the Smart Card prompt. We do not and have never had smart cards in our organisation.

Comment: Add `-cert` parameter to explicitly specify certificate name (serial number or thumbprint, for example).

Comment: Hmmm, I thought of that but was hoping to avoid as this is part of a script and would be run by any one of a number of administrators. I'd have to query their certificate store for the details.

Comment: Then you cannot prevent this popup. Certreq attempts to find suitable signing certificate silently. However, you have installed smart card driver and middlevare and when certreq queries the smart card, a popup is invoked. The only way to avoid the popup is to specify signing cert explicitly.

Comment: Ok, many thanks - I'll use Powershell to query the local certificate store for the thumbprint of the certificate with Request Agent enhanced usage.

Comment: Right, this one has me stumped - whereabouts in the syntax do I Insert the correct thumbprint?
This seems correct from the help documentation, but still prompts for a certificate

certreq -config "CertAuth" -policy -cert "thumbprint" "PathtoCSR" "Path to SanDetails.inf" "NewCSROutputPath"

Comment: Windows caches the smart card certificate. Try removing the smart card and delete the cached certificate using certmgr.msc.

Comment: Thats the thing. We don;t have smart cards and there are no certificates for them.

I've verified that the syntax is correct as per my edited question - but it still prompts for smartcard before using the certificate named in the request. Therefore my original question still stands - how to remove the smartcard prompt.

Comment: What is the number of computers that you have verified this behavior?

Comment: Received it on 3 separate computers so far - all Win10

Comment: I am have the same exact issue, and for me, even putting the thumbprint in does not prevent the certificate selection pop up.  So having two popups is a pain.  Did you ever find a way to prevent the smartcard popup?

Comment: No, I eventually had to write notification into the script telling the user to cancel the Smartcard prompt. Microsoft really need some native Powershell commands for this process.

Comment: yeah, thats terrible.  you are right microsoft really does need something for this.  One last thing, you use `-cert [EACertThumbprint]` and it auto selects the EA cert when resigning?  because i can’t seem to get that work.  I can i guess settle on 1 prompt, but i really don’t want 2 prompts.